# magento2 RMA. How to plug RMA

Tags: magento2, rma

Searched the entire Internet and did not find information about RMA on magento2.
Tell me how to connect RMA to my magento2? Is it possible?

I have CE magento2

Comment: Check https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/sales/returns.html

Comment: I have CE magento2, not EE.

Comment: Then you need to go with thrid party RMA extension. RMA is for EE, not CE.